# How to check the default handler for a specific file type in Terminal?

Tags: command-line, files, default-programs, file-format, file-properties

I often come across file types which I am not sure of, but yet need to open, but as I don't know what the default file handler on my system is for that specific file type (and sometimes the file doesn't even have an extension, so that makes it even harder for me to tell), I am unable to open and display it in its correct format. I could just launch Nautilus, however I would prefer to do as much as I can of it in the CLI, and sometimes I am doing this in console so I can't just launch a file manager. So how in Terminal can I tell what if any is the default file handler for a given file? I am on Ubuntu Gnome 15.04.

Comment: `file yourfile` will give you some idea about the file type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the command `file` or `mimetype`

EG

```
% file conf.ini 
conf.ini: ASCII text

% mimetype conf.ini 
conf.ini: text/plain

% file Screenshot\ from\ 2015-08-17\ 20-32-54.png 
Screenshot from 2015-08-17 20-32-54.png: PNG image data, 1112 x 700, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced

% mimetype Screenshot\ from\ 2015-08-17\ 20-32-54.png
Screenshot from 2015-08-17 20-32-54.png: image/png

% file Intro.mp3
Intro.mp3: Audio file with ID3 version 2.3.0

% mimetype Intro.mp3 
Intro.mp3: audio/mpeg
```

And to show the default desktop file for the mime type of a given file

```
% mimetype -b Screenshot\ from\ 2015-08-17\ 20-32-54.png |\
    xargs xdg-mime query default
eog.desktop
```

Or the application call

```
% mimetype -b Screenshot\ from\ 2015-08-17\ 20-32-54.png | \
    xdg-mime query default |
    xargs -i'{}' awk -F= '/^Exec/ {print $2}' "/usr/share/applications/{}" 
eog %U
```

Comment: ..like I said ;)

Comment: @Ron Sorry, same idea =)

Comment: ... once you have the mime type, you can use the `xdg-mime` utility to query the default application for that type e.g. `xdg-mime query default image/png` or `xdg-mime query default text/plain`